# How to capture and prefix to process output started within a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing a small bash script where I am compiling 2 programs then executing them in the background within a bash script. These 2 programs do output some generic text. However I need to prefix these outputs like `PROGRAM1: xxxxx`. How do I achieve that? I have found several answers here however they weren't exactly applicable to this situation.

Here's the code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "This program compiles 2 programs, executes them (executes the 2nd one first, then sleeps for 0.01 second which then executes program 1), then observes the outputs"

gcc -O3 -std=c11 one.c -o one
gcc -O3 -std=c11 two.c -o two

./two &
sleep 0.01
TWO_PID=$(pgrep two)

./one $TWO_PID

#"Prefix output statements here"
#add code here

#Cleanup
rm -f one two
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
#! /bin/bash

# ...

label() {
    while read -r l; do
        echo "$1: $l"
    done
}

./two | label "two" &
two_pid=$(pgrep two)
./one $two_pid | label "one"
```

You don't need the sleep and be careful as `pgrep` could match more than one process.

Also, instead of compiling and removing you should use `make`.

Comment: I need to do the sleep as it's requirement for a practice problem I'm working on.

Comment: "Also, instead of compiling and removing you should use make." Do you mean to have a makefile in same directory and just call make within the bash script? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Usually making and running are separate things but you can invoke make from the script if you want, at least it won't make it if sources didn't change.